# How to review the cache while a django app is running

Tags: django, caching

Is it possible to view the contents of the cache (memcache, locmemcache or any other) while a django app is running? eg via the admin screens, or some other library?

Comment: This might not be an exact answer, but could give you an alternative: http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into the Django admin interface to view the status of the cache, so:

- You can [telnet into memcache](http://lzone.de/articles/memcached.htm) via the command line if you want to see its status.
- You could use some third party Django applications, for example [`django-admin-cache`](https://github.com/bartTC/django-memcache-status).
- You could use some third party Python applications, for example [`python-memcached-stats`](There is nothing built into the Django admin interface to view the status of the cache, but there are some)
- [You could write your own Django admin views to see the status of the cache](http://effbot.org/zone/django-memcached-view.htm) (be warned that the linked article is from 2007)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and I will provide 2 possibilities, when using **memcached** as your caching service.

**First Option: NO CODEing REQUIRED**

For some quick monitoring of a running memcached system:

[ Installing in ubuntu ]

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmemcached-tools
```

[ Installing in rhel/fedora ]

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rpm
```

This includes a handful of handy tools. The one in particular that I use is **memcstat** in ubuntu, and the redhat rpm comes with a **memcached-tool**

[ Using in ubuntu ]

```
$ watch -n1 -d 'memcstat --servers localhost'
```

[ Using in rhel/fedora ]

```
$ watch -n1 -d 'memcached-tool localhost:11211 stats'
```

This will show alot of handy **memcached** information like for instance:

```
curr_connections: 5
total_connections: 26

-- snip --

get_hits: 202
get_misses: 12

-- snip --

bytes_read: 1650
bytes_written: 74345
```

This is handy because it does not require you to write a single line of code, and better yet will tell you if your caching infrastructure is working like you expect it too.

**Second option: Building A Handy Management command**

First go get and install [MemcachedStats](https://github.com/dlrust/python-memcached-stats)

```
---- <django-app>/management/commands/list_memcachedstats.py ----

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from memcached_stats import MemcachedStats
import pprint

class Command( BaseCommand ):
    def handle( self, *args, **options ):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = '11211'
        m = MemcachedStats(host, port)
        pprint.pprint(m.keys())
```

Now to use this simply:

```
$ python ./manage.py list_memcachedstats
```

Sometimes it is also handy to know how many keys you have in memcached:

```
$ python ./manage.py list_memcachedstats |wc -l
```

This can be handy when growing the keylist.

**Finally**

You can use either one, or both of these techniques while your django system is running.